# Permission Denied to modify tasks and cpu.shares

Tags: linux, bash, containers, cgroups

As an experiment I was trying to add some processes in `tasks` and modify some `cpu.shares`. However I get Permission denied if I try to run commands like

I created a folder `test` inside of `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu`

```
$ sudo -s
$whoami
root

$ echo 2472 > tasks
-bash: tasks: Permission denied

$sudo echo 10 > cpu.shares
-bash: cpu.shares: Permission denied
```

Also, an ls of the folder does not show these 2 files. (Because no PIDs in the task file??)

Also, if I try to delete the `test` folder, I cant. I get the error

```
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.events': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/io.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.procs': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.max.descendants': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cpu.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/memory.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cpu.pressure': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.type': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.stat': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.threads': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.kill': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.freeze': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.controllers': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.subtree_control': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'test/cgroup.max.depth': Operation not permitted
```

But why am I not able to edit these files or delete this created folder?
I tried running the commands as a root user
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: Did you try sudo echo 10 > cpu.shares ?

Comment: `sudo ` doesn't work either

Comment: This is probably more appropriate on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/5/cgconfig.conf

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for anyone running into the same issue. I fixed it by running "rmdir" instead of "rm".